# Multiple one to one relationship - insert new record problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, relationship, one-to-one

- Backend: SQL Server
- Frontend: MS Access

So here are the tables to represent the issue:

`Master` is like a class and the child table are subclass of master, so `Master` will contain data that is common to all children and child contains specific data

(let's say master is a pump table and child1 will be electrical and child2 diesel pump data)

Master table (test_1) :

```
ID : INT pk
A : nvarchar
```

Type1 table (test_2) :

```
ID : INT pk
B : nvarchar
```

Type2 table (test_3)

```
ID : INT pk
C : nvarchar
```

What is working :

- Any existing record can be edited no problem for any quantity of Type
- Insert a record in master only then edit subchild is working

What is not working :

- Insert a record in master and edit child child at the same time

Using left join of children on master and trying to add a new record, value A can be entered then C but when trying to input B I have the following error

> Cannot add record: primary key for table Type2 not in recordset

Query:

```
SELECT 
    dbo_T_TEST1.ID, dbo_T_TEST1.A, 
    dbo_T_TEST2.B, dbo_T_TEST3.C
FROM
    (dbo_T_TEST1 
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo_T_TEST2 ON dbo_T_TEST1.ID = dbo_T_TEST2.ID) 
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo_T_TEST3 ON dbo_T_TEST1.ID = dbo_T_TEST3.ID;
```

Output:

```
ID ----------> ID
A     |         B
      |
      -------> ID
               C
```

The idea is to be able to add a new record in the master and if required add child's value at the same time

The easy way out (but not clean) is to have a table containing MASTER+CHILD+CHILD in a single table but I will create a lot of NULL values as a master is linked to only one child type

Another solution is to create some subquery/subform for MASTER to a single child (that works but required many subform)

Comment: I have a laboratory db with master table that has many 1-to-1 related child tables. My solution is a process where users enter sample info main record and select laboratory tests to perform and related child records are created. Then after tests are performed, a single form with a recordset of all tables is opened for input of test data.

Comment: Yes, like I said creating the master "then" enter child info is working, but we are looking to be able to create master "and" enter child info in the same query / form / action without doing requery (requery that take long time as the info are on cloud server)

Comment: Perhaps you need to explore UNBOUND forms and lot more VBA to manage this?

Comment: VBA will work, as you can easily insert into with some code, but at the end of all the insert, the form will need to call the requery that will take approx 6 sec to complete.

Comment: Why requery? If form is unbound there is nothing to requery.

Comment: there is no such thing as inserting at the same time. The master record has to be created, saved, and the autonumber PK generated. Only then can you add child records to the respective tables.